# How sklearn IterativeImputer works under the hood?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, statistics, data-science

[IterativeImputer's Documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/impute.html#multivariate-feature-imputation)

Official documentation of IterativeImputer states that the

> "A regressor is fit on (X, y) for known y. Then, the regressor is used to predict the missing values of y. This is done for each feature in an iterative fashion, and then is repeated for max_iter imputation rounds. The results of the final imputation round are returned."

Now assuming that dataframe X has columns (x1, x2, x3, x4, x5) and missing values are confined to column x5 only.
From what official doc mentions a regressor is fitted for each column taking x1..x4 as input data and available x5 values as output value.

So once the regression model(r1..r4) is trained and they have predicted missing value for x5, we have 4 different candidate value for each of the missing data. How is the imputer determining what value to return or is the returning the mean of all 4 or is it done some other way?

I would highly appreciate if you could answer with a simple example so that it would be easy for beginners like me to understand.

Comment: Why do you think you'll have 4 candidates? Scikit will predict exactly one value for any missing value.

Comment: Now I'm super confused, isn't it creating one regressor for each available feature with respect to the missing ones?